# elif <= invalid syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

i am currently working on a calculator using pandas, and to determine a variable I have used a nested if statement. But unfortunately, I get an invalid syntax error from the below code.

```
    if net_option == 'Y':
        if age <= 30:
            desired_net = 0.15
        elif age >= 31 and <= 60:
            desired_net = 0.12
        elif age >= 61 and <= 90:
            desired_net = 0.11
        elif age >= 91 and <= 140:
            desired_net = 0.10
        elif age >= 141 and <= 180:
            desired_net = 0.09
        elif age >= 181 and <= 245:
            desired_net = 0.08
        elif age >= 246 and <= 270:
            desired_net = 0.07
        elif age >= 271 and <= 365:
            desired_net = 0.6
        elif age >= 366 and <= 500:
            desired_net = 0.3
        elif: age >= 501 and <= 700:
            desired_net = 0.0
        elif age > 700:
            desired_net = -0.1
        else:
            desired_net = 0.1
    else:
        desired_net = desired_net
```

Error message:

```
elif age >= 31 and <= 60:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think I am missing something here as I am pretty sure that <= is a valid syntax.

Has anyone got an idea what may be wrong? Let me know if you would like to see more lines.

Comment: `and age <= 60`

Comment: @kaya3 Or `31 <= age <= 60`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elif age >= 31 and age <= 60:`

When using the `and` operator, you are required to write the variable to compare against again, because each expression before and after `and` stands on its own.

Comment: Or `31 <= age <= 60`.

Comment: Terminology note: `age >= 31` and `age <= 60` before and after `and` are expressions, not statements.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you use Numpy, you could make your code much more simple and functionalize the logic like this:

```
def get_desired_net(age):   
    desired_net = {0:0.15, 31:0.12, 61:0.11, 91:0.10, 141:0.09, 181:0.08, 246:0.07, 271:0.06, 366:0.03, 501:0.00, 701:-0.01}

    keys_array = np.array(list(desired_net.keys()))

    max_age = max(keys_array[keys_array <= age])

    return desired_net[max_age]

>>> get_desired_net(15)
0.15
>>> get_desired_net(30)
0.15
>>> get_desired_net(31)
0.12
>>> get_desired_net(700)
0.0
>>> get_desired_net(701)
-0.01
```